# Where should I use iostream class?

Tags: c++, stream, iostream

As we know in C++ we have class iostream, which is inherited from istream(basic_istream) and ostream (basic_ostream). In every C++ book you can find, that with iostream class object you can read and write to the same  stream. But I realy haven't see any explanation or example to understand why should I use such a strange think. I really don't know why should I need to write to some stream and than read from it :(.

Could you explain me when I should need such construction? I think there must be serous reason for using such construction(don't forget that only for iostream declaration we are using virtual inheritance and multiple inheritance).

Also when I try to write a simple code, which is using fsteram(derivative of iostream) I find, that its not working in  way, which I expect. Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int  main()
{
    fstream fstr("somefile.txt",fstream::in|fstream::out);//fstream is deriveted from iosteram
    int n;
    fstr>>n;//reading n (WORKS FINE !!!).

    fstr.flush();

    //trying to print Hello to the same file
    fstr<<"Hello"<<endl;// NOT WORKING!!!!!!!

    fstr.flush();

    return 0;
}
```

So could you tell me why this code can read from file and can't write something to it????

Resume:
Please tell me why we need class iosteram and why isteram and ostream arn't enought and how to use it.

Thanks and sorry for my english :).

P.S. Probably this question is to primitive, but please answer me.

Edit: My code is now working. Thanks to Murka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read from and write to the same stream because the stream performs type conversions, like std::stringstream. You could also have iostream abstractions over data sources that permit both reading and writing- such as a socket or an in-memory buffer.

Comment: Ok, than could you explain why I need fstream and what I'm doing wrong in my code?

Comment: @Ashot: If you want to ask about iostream in general, open one question. If you want to ask about specific code with fstream, open another question. The two aren't related.

Answer (score 4):

IIRC you need to do a seek before you can write, don't ask why.
Also added code to clear any flags it might raise.

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int  main()
{
    fstream fstr("somefile.txt",fstream::in|fstream::out);//fstream is deriveted from iosteram
    int n;
    fstr>>n;//reading n (WORKS FINE !!!).

    fstr.clear();     //Clear any errors, eof, etc.
    fstr.seekg(0, ios::beg);  //Seek to beginning of file
    fstr.flush();

    //trying to print Hello to the same file
    fstr<<"Hello"<<endl;// NOW WORKS!!!

    fstr.flush();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> why should i need ability to read and
>   write to the file at the same time?

You might need that ability for a program that *updates* or edits an existing file: it must read what is already present, to locate the part to be updated or edited, and must write the update (alteration) to the file.

Comment: Ok, than could you tell me what I'm doing wrong in my example? Also don't you think that having 2 objects ifstream and ofstream more logical. And if it's a explanation than, I think that fstream is unneeded. Maybe iostream isn't usless becouse using sockets as a streams sounds good to me but in case of files  I think using ifstream and ofstream are much better

Answer (score 0):

> when I should need such construction

Rarely. See my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517299/is-fstream-better-than-iostream-in-c/4517883#4517883

Edited:
If you don't think you need it, you don't need it.

Comment: @Readwald. Ok,  I also think, that in your example it's better to write std::istream or std::ostream, but my question is why should i need ability to read and write to the file at the same time?